# How to handle new properties to object in flow

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I have a function which checks the status code of a `fetch` response and throws an error so that I can use catch to handle it. I am using flow which  doesn't like it that I pass the response to the Error object which I need in order to handle the correct statuscode and to have a nice promis chaining.

```js
const StatusCodeHandler = (response: { statusText: string, ok: string }) => {
  if (response.ok) return response;
  const error = new Error(response.statusText);
  error.response = response;
  throw error;
};
```

it should look something like this when I am using it:

```js
fetch(url).then(StatucCodeHandler)
          .then(respone=>response.json())
          .catch(error=>handleError(error.response.status));
....
```

In `handleError`I will do specific actions depending on the statuscode.

What is the propper way to do that with flow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most proper way would probably be to define a custom error class by subclassing `Error`.

```
class RequestError extends Error {
  response: Response;
  constructor(message: string, response: Response) {
    super(message);
    this.response = response;
    this.message = message;
  }
};

const StatusCodeHandler = (response: Response) => {
  if (response.ok) return response;
  throw new RequestError(response.statusText, response);
};
```

([Try](https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEBMHsDsHIBdQFcDOBTU8AWBLFAaZdTLDAAwCU0UAHGdM0AYwBsBDFFCNAMx2jThQAIwCeoHi0gB3WFxY5hwYZAC2AOgBWKdQCgQoHIhRZISFkOEZwvfoMPRQoswCdQaaADccLmKo+IwkiIRoZc0JCINnwCQvygACouonqsHFxUtPQYAN6guqCgKPBs8KgJaAAe8ABcRfAu-ADmANwFoJAA1nXFjdCtugC+bbppnKBUAI5I1PAAoi6+blXwHuBcC0ugOe0u1HTQ6HWZB+hthUz0DUhM8JAuABT+nGxNaD0NzYR7WYfvE-tsgBKbbtQooJA0NCPZ4oV5oIHnQokPDqH6nDAAXlA6OySMK2FRsPhoGxxLeSMGQxGl0OiAAyiUyigAMKQGwACTY0HALGhpNAD1xf2OgL+IMxAD5QYUcDxBcL0OouiC9mUXI5FWgkdhfNJQAJ9VMZsVNvchWKlcVSuUVt9LQi2sMgA))

If you're using a babel version earlier than 7, you'll want [transform-builtin-classes](https://github.com/WebReflection/babel-plugin-transform-builtin-classes) to allow subclasing the builtin `Error`.

Answer (score 0):

2nd method with `then` and `catch` is a better way. Because of Better handling of asynchronous operations, Better flow of control definition in asynchronous logic etc advantages.

Comment: Are you refering to the second code block of my post?That is exactly what I am aiming for but for that I need the response in the error so that I can access the different statuscodes in ```handleError```